# Is it possible to select all the series by one click?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am drawing a bubble chart in `Excel 2010`.

I would like each bubble to be associated with its (film) name.

What I cannot do is creating only 1 serie for all the films, and formatting its data label as `Series Name`, because in that case each bubble will have a long list of all the film names along side it.

So currently what I can do is to create 1 serie for 1 film, then select one bubble and format its data label as `Series Name`, as follows:

[image]

The problem now is that I may have many films, so I have to repeat the selecting of the bubble and formatting the data label... Does anyone know how to select all the series by one click, or format their data label by one click?

Comment: I could patch up some VBA-code for this or you could use a chart-template - but I would like to know your dataseries-setup first. Could you add, how your dataseries are defined exactly?